# InfoPath 2010, SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010, readonly

I have created an InfoPath 2010 form which is published to doc library in SharePoint 2010. I want for this form to become read-only ie once it has been submitted.

None of what I have done so far seems to work. I have:

1. Created a new view and re-named it to Read-Only and in its properties I have ticked 
   the "Read-Only" check box in InfoPath.
2. I have a "Submit Form" button and in here I have added rules for submitting the form, 
   switching the view to the read-only view.
3. To test this I fill out the form with sample data and submit it,  then when I go to 
   the doc library where the forms gets submitted to when I open the submitted form I 
   find that the Read-Only view has not taken effect and that it is still possible to 
   edit the form.

Ideally what I am trying to achieve is to have the submitted forms turned into read-only when they are submitted and still be in read-only mode when these are opened from the document library where they get submitted to.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong with this? if there is a better and simpler way to achieve this please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late to answer this question, but if someone is still looking for an answer you could try the below steps

1. Before you begin please verify that you have one of the following permissions:
   a. You are a member of the Administrators group for the site collection.
   b. You are a member of the Owners group for the site.
   c. You have the Manage Permissions permission.
2. On the Site Settings page, Go to the Users and Permissions and look for settings
3. Under Settings you will be able to see Permission Levels
4. Select Add a Permission Level
5. Give a Name to you new Permission Level
6. Under the Select the Permissions to include to this permission level, select the Add Items and View Items Permissions to this group.
7. After the group is created, for your form library, stop inheriting the permissions from the parent site and create a new group with the new Permission Level that you just created. Add all the users to the group.

This should enable the users to submit a form but not edit it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to solve this. Create two views of this form on InfoPath Designer. And make sure when the form is submitted, the view is flipped to the Read-Only view; which has the salient feartures of the form such as the answers you would like to be recorded.

So anyone who opens the form once submitted wil only see the Read-Only view. You can set a rule on the form to have an administrator see a Edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this.  the submit rule doesn't work, you have to create a form load rule.  In the file toolbar, you'll see a form load button in the rules block.